# Problems with ViewPager / Fragments bottomLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

What's up. I'm using a viewPager with 3 other fragments. Each fragment contains their own components. One of this components it's a `LinearLayout` that I set it as `alignParentBottom="true"`. Although, when I turn on the App, I can't barely see the content of this bottom. Anyone knows how to fix this?

MainActivity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.victorvicari.actionbarteste.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="false" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorTextFloatingBtn"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorTextFloatingBtn"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="80dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footerLayout"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view_dividerBottom"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footerLayout"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.8dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/footerLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Partial:"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:id="@+id/textViewRecebeVlrParcialFrag2"/>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to use `match_parent` for your `ViewPager` height

Comment: I already did, and the problem remains

Comment: The problem is "RecyclerView" in your fragment layout. don't set it to "match_parent" and you will see your bottom layout.